# Please tell me about smart asset

Tags: smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

This is an example of the Waves IDE.

Please let me know how to transfer this smart asset token.　m(__)m

```
match tx {case tx : TransferTransaction =>
let issuer = Address(base58'3MsZgp7XvTJV7TuqaZ46RJZuG2CtvcxYgC9')
isDefined(getInteger(issuer, toBase58String(tx.id)))
case m :SetAssetScriptTransaction | SetScriptTransaction =>true
case _ => false
}
```

I am the issuer. Do I add something to this Json and POST?

Share the Link to Sign↓

```
{
"version": 2,
"assetId": "GMpv7cLThamxe7sHh5n52zZFKcHqPU4GAmxGXTxwRA2A",
"amount": 100000,
"feeAssetId": "",
"fee": 500000,
"recipient": "3Muet8GgfyC6Xd1Qv7TNjqT2N4dUwmJPfXC",
"attachment": "",
"timestamp": 1554080004122,
"senderPublicKey": "9QYYVjZntWane75e8ZyoacJdtrfUhuCTSYctVTqxTnJM",
"proofs": ["SoFHDJY6SMUyY8a4t2ZiEFgdc8DRUCcBUNcqrPjfbjgvq7bg74TJKdBw8UHDunKpg9GhjSw7QRXh4VMhuNcPdjm"],
"type": 4
}
```

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

1. you issue an asset with this script(7th line should contain issuer's
   your address).
2. you create transferTx but not broadcast it
3. you get id of this transaction and send a dataTx from issuer's
   address: data: [{key: , value: 100}]
4. now you're allowed to send the tx that you've generated earlier and
   you can broadcast it now

   ```
   {-# STDLIB_VERSION 3 #-}
   {-# CONTENT_TYPE EXPRESSION #-}
   {-# SCRIPTTYPE ASSET #-}

   match tx {
       case tx : TransferTransaction =>
           let issuer = Address(base58'3MsZgp7XvTJV7TuqaZ46RJZuG2CtvcxYgC9')
           isDefined(getInteger(issuer, toBase58String(tx.id)))
       case m : SetAssetScriptTransaction =>true
       case  => false
   }
   ```

from here you should issue the token:
[image]

after you click on issue token, you need to define 3 variables: `"name": "your token name", "quantity":1000000, "description": "for testing"`,
after that follow the steps above.
example of transfer tx:

```
const tx = transfer({amount: 10, recipient: "recipient address"})
```

example of Datatx:

```
const DataTx = data({data: [{key: "transfer transaction id", value: 100}]})
broadcast(tx)
```

to find the transfer transaction ID, you just need to type it's name in the console(for example `tx`)